# How to install python on windows without admin privilege

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was looking to install python on my school computer so that I can code at school, but I don't have any admin privileges.

So far I've downloaded python using

```
msiexec /a python-2.7.14.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:\filepath
```

Then I set the path to python.exe using

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Now when I run `python` in the command prompt I get

> This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

Is there a way around this, or will I not be able to run python without admin privileges? Thanks!

Comment: [Anacodna](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos)

Comment: The error message you're getting suggests to me that your network is using Software Restriction Policy or similar. That is, there's a strict whitelist of .exe files that you're allowed to execute. If your application is not on that master list, you don't get to execute anything.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck "install for everyone" and you should be able to install without admin rights (Checked on windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html). That allows installation of Python without admin rights. And please use Python 3.6 unless you have a very good reason to use the old 2.7, also called legacy Python.

Comment: No, this didn't. Whenever I run "start /wait "" Miniconda4-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=%UserProfile%\Miniconda3" I get "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator."